# A.C. through resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

There is a topic in my physics book "A.C through resistance". And in this topic there is a sentence " the applied voltage has to overcome the drop in resistance I.e V=IR."

What do we mean by this? Why would applied voltage need to overcome drop in resistance and how will it do it?

Comment: It means *the applied voltage has to overcome **the voltage drop across the resistance*** i.e. $V = IR$.

Comment: I didn't get it...why would it do that and how? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think john meant that the voltage drop across the resistace V = IR is not costant and depends on time (voltage in AC is not costant). If you have only a AC generator and a resistance in your circuit the voltage drop needs to be equal to the voltage of the generator (see kirchhoff law)

Comment: I want to use hydraulic analogy so voltage = pressure but then voltage isn't a force at all... I'll think of something else ;D

Comment: But lorenzo voltage drop and applied voltage will never be equal right...

Answer (score 0):

The phrase simply states the following two key ideas regarding potential difference, resistance and current in AC, that

1. In a circuit with a purely resistive load, the potential difference across the resistance is always equal to the potential difference across the EMF device. And, that
2. In an AC circuit with a purely resistive load, the alternating current in the resistance is IN PHASE with the alternating potential difference across the resistance; that is, the phase constant Φ for the current is zero.

Comment: But what does it mean by "that A.V has to overcome the drop in resistance? Why would it need to do that? Also In an A.C circuit will the p.d across resistor be equal to voltage source at any time?